# HTML/CSS/JS: large, scrolling and zooming tile grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I want to create a front-end to basically visualize a 2-dimensional array. It's a **large** grid, large enough that the tiles may boil down to single pixels when looking at it from afar.

I'd like to implement zooming and 2d scrolling to navigate the representation (which is nothing more than colored squares).

What's the easiest way to go about this? This is not the part of the project i'm the most interested in, so I'd like to avoid having to learn huge frameworks.

I'm perfectly willing to use a `canvas` and/or `JS/CSS` techniques over elements.

Answer (score 0):

the 2d-dimensional array will have some pattern? will be any image or something? to represent some like the automata rule110 or some simple/half-advanceg graphics canvas is a great option or frameworks like KineticJS

Comment: It's just your regular 2d array with integers in the range `0:3` or so, represented by colored squares.

Comment: you want to represent the 2d-array in a table? each value in the 2d-array will represent some color ?

Comment: Yes. I didn't say `table` because I didn't want to hint at using an actual `<table>`, leaving the matter open

Answer (score -1):

this code is for canvas

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script>
var arr = new Array(new Array(1,2,3), new Array(1,2,1), new Array(2,3,1));
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var size = 10;
for(var i=0; i< 3;i++){
    for(var j=0; j< 3;j++){
        if(arr[i][j]==1){
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        }else if(arr[i][j]==2) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        }else if(arr[i][j]==3){
        ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        }

        ctx.fillRect(i*(size+1),j*(size+1),size,size);
    }
}
</script>
```